# What does "a paper of sandwiches" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, literature

I am quoting from the TV series "The Memoirs of Sherlock Holmes" (episode 3, "The Naval Treaty"):

> After leaving at the station I went for a charming walk through some admirable Surrey scenery to a pretty little village called Ripley, where I had my tea at an inn, and took the precaution of filling my flask and of putting a paper of sandwiches in my pocket.

Comment: "Sandwiches" is clearly a plural form, so why do you think that it might refer to a single item?

Comment: just got confused by the word a paper

Comment: OK, I did some light editing to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: thank you very much for taking time to do it

Comment: It's a rare, archaic pseudopartitive (compare the common 'a bag of sweets'). 'Container' and contents are referenced; the 'container' is a paper wrapping.

Comment: thank you very much Edwin It's much clearer now

Answer (score 5):

It probably means "sandwiches wrapped in (greaseproof) paper".

In 19th century England there were no plastic bags or plastic lunch boxes. Greaseproof paper was traditionally used for food packaging, both informally and commercially (and still is).

"Sandwiches" is the plural form of "sandwich".

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful

Comment: Definitely so. It's how Mum wrapped my sandwiches in the 1950s.

Comment: @Duckspindle and Weather Vane, I wonder what that's like, the greaseproof paper?  Is it the same as waxed paper?

Comment: @aparente001 [greaseproof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greaseproof_paper) is a generic term for waterproof papers. Parchment paper was used for centuries for food wrapping, and waxed paper isn't suitable for cooking.

Comment: @aparente001 From my experience of reading American recipes I think that the US equivalent of the British "greaseproof paper" is "baking parchment".

Comment: @BoldBen and Weather Vane,  Okay, parchment.  I have such a thing but I didn't realize it was greaseproof. But Vane, does one typically cook sandwiches?

Comment: @aparente001 if they are toasted, yes :) but greaseproof paper is used to wrap food: uncooked, during cooking, or after being cooked.

Comment: I'm thinking the sandwich that went in the pocket wouldn't have been square.  In Mexico one makes sandwiches out of *pambazo* which is a round roll.  Cut in half, pull out some of the innards, and the contents don't get squeezed out as easily as in the US square sandwich.  Also, in the individually wrapped Mexican sandwich, the paper (could be an unfolded napkin) can be adjusted as the sandwich is getting smaller, to keep everything neat and tidy, without falling apart.

Comment: @WeatherVane - How do you toast a sandwich that's already wrapped?  Wouldn't the  sandwich get toasted first, and wrapped second?

Comment: How do we know a sandwich didn't grow out of a roll?

Comment: @boldben, Greaseproof paper and baking parchment are not the same.  Also, it appears that greaseproof paper is not the same thing on both sides of the Atlantic, being waxed in the US and unwaxed in the UK. Baking parchment is treated with silicones to make it non-stick. Here's a UK manufacturer's take on it. As for other sources, it seems there are as many different definitions as there are websites: https://www.bacofoil.co.uk/faq/what-is-the-difference-between-baking-paper-greaseproof-paper/

Comment: @aparente001 In Victorian Britain the sandwiches would, almost certainly, have been either approximately rectangular or approximately D-shaped depending on the type of loaf from which they were cut. A filled roll (if such a thing was common at that time, which I doubt) would not have been called a sandwich.

Comment: @aparente001 in Victorian Britain a sandwich was made from 2 slices of bread from a loaf. A filled roll is called a roll, 'sandwich' being a recent imported term for a filled roll.

Comment: Ah, filled roll.  Good term.